# Sent form isn't complete. Some fields are near by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

When I am sending new form, some fields aren't put in final map - they are just near by. Have no idea why is it happening...

**View - sending**

```
<%= form_for :review, :url => { :action => "show" } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :owner %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :owner %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :special %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :special %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :overview %><br />
    <%= text_area_tag(:overview, "", :size => "24x6") %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag(:service_overview, "overview") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:service, "overview") %>
    <%= label_tag(:service_repair, "repair") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:service, "repair") %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Migration**

```
create_table :reviews do |t|
  t.string :owner
  t.string :service
  t.string :overview
  t.boolean :special
  t.integer :cost
  t.timestamps
end
```

edit - and of course:
**Server log**

```
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Next", "overview"=>"123123", "service"=>"repair", "re
view"=>{"special"=>"1", "owner"=>"aaaa"}, "authenticity_token"=>"HehoAEoQRvLwFL9
yZsbBXzy4PI9a53JjtfM4rqtMUt8=", "utf8"=>"Ôťô"}
```

Ok, I see, that in HTML there is difference between tags which are included in sent map and these, which aren't:

```
  <input id="review_special" name="review[special]" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input id="service_overview" name="service" type="radio" value="overview">
```

but still no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Why are you using two different form helpers in the same form? t.radio_button and radio_button_tag are different form helpers, if you are gonna go for consistency you should probably either use one or the other.

Comment: thank you, I've just figured it out